# How to find the maximum value of the following difference equation without using iterative method？

Tags: differential-equations

$E(i+1)=(I-AT)E(i)+1/2(AT)^2$

How to find the maximum value of $E$ in this expression without using the iterative method? An approximate estimation is also acceptable. Only the $E$ vector is unknown, and the others are known matrix vectors.

It would be better if we could get a formula of $E$ about $T$.

Comment: Hi, I edited your question. For the future, it would be better if you used MathJax for mathematical expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and modifications. Could you tell me how to use MathJax? Because I haven't used it for a long time, I don't know much about its usage. And I want to reply to the specified user in the comments section. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: See here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3763/how-does-one-type-mathematical-formulas-on-this-site

Comment: Fine, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your request "It would be better if we could get a formula of $E$":

By induction on $i$,
$$E(i)=B^i E(0)+\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} B^jC \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for $i=0,1,\dots$, where $B:=I-AT$ and $C:=1/2(AT)^2$.

If $(I-B)^{-1}$ exists, then $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} B^j=(I-B^i)(I-B)^{-1}$ and hence \eqref{1} can be rewritten as
$$E(i)=B^i (E(0)-(I-B)^{-1}C)+(I-B)^{-1}C. \tag{2}\label{2}$$

---

(As for your other request, "How to find the maximum value of $E$", it is incomprehensible to me, as $E(i)$ apparently is a *vector* function of $i$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It will help me a lot. I have another small problem. For the formula $(2)$ you gave, Could I make $\frac{\partial E(I)}{\partial i}=0$ and get the value of zero point $i$, take the value of $i$ back to equation $(2)$, and then find the maximum value of $E(i)$?

Comment: @chenchen : No, you can't differentiate with respect to $i$, since $i$ is an integer.

Comment: Then do I have to use iterative method to solve formula $(2)$? It's really a headache haha. How do I specify to reply to you? Use this@

Comment: @chenchen : As I wrote in my answer, "How to find the maximum value of $E$" is really incomprehensible to me, as $E(i)$ apparently is a *vector* function of $i$. Unless you speak in clear and correct mathematical language, I will be unable to understand or help you.